# how to parse multiple query params and pass them to a sql command

Tags: mysql, rest, go

i am playing around rest API's in go and when i do a get call with this

> http://localhost:8000/photos?albumId=1&id=1

i want to return only those values from db which corresponds to alubmId=1 and id =1 , or any other key in the query for that matter without storing as variables and then passing it to query, and when i dont give any query params i want it to return all the posts in db

```
  func getPhotos(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            var photos []Photo

            db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:$pwd@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/typicode")
            if err != nil {
                    panic(err.Error())
            }

            defer db.Close()

            for k, v := range r.URL.Query() {
                    fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", k, v)
            }

            result, err := db.Query("SELECT id, albumId, Title,thumbnailUrl,url from photo")
            if err != nil {
                    panic(err.Error())
            }

            defer result.Close()

            for result.Next() {
                    var photo Photo
                    err := result.Scan(&photo.Id, &photo.AlbumId, &photo.Title, &photo.Url, &photo.Thumbnailurl)
                    if err != nil {
                            panic(err.Error())
                    }
                    photos = append(photos, photo)
            }
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(photos)
    }
```

Comment: *"without storing as variables and then passing it to query"* Why? How else would you tell the database which rows should be returned? How else would you filter the table records if not by using a `WHERE`, or `HAVING`, clause with search conditions?

Comment: @mkopriva what i mean is abouve the query we are looping thtough URL.Query and getting albumId and Id, this are got in 2 iterations, i want to get it in a single iteration, so that i can pass them using WHERE clause. Right now i have two variables album id and id , passing the values got from the loop assiging it these variable and then pass to query, i dont want to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a set of valid table columns that can be used in the query, this is required to avoid unnecessary errors from columns with typos and sql injections from malicious input.

```
var photocolumns = map[string]struct{}{
    "id":      {},
    "albumId": {},
    // all the other columns you accept as input
}
```

Now depending on the database you may, or you may not, need to parse the query values and convert them to the correct type for the corresponding column. You can utilize the column map to associate each column with the correct converter type/func.

```
// a wrapper around strconv.Atoi that has the signature of the map-value type below
func atoi(s string) (interface{}, error) {
    return strconv.Atoi(s)
}

var photocolumns = map[string]func(string) (interface{}, error) {
    "id":      atoi,
    "albumId": atoi,
    // all the other columns you accept as input
}
```

Then, all you need is a single loop and in it you do all the work you need. You get the correct column name, convert the value to the correct type, aggregate that converted value into a slice so that it can be passed to the db, and also construct the WHERE clause so that it can be concatenated to the sql query string.

```
where := ""
params := []interface{}{}
for k, v := range r.URL.Query() {
    if convert, ok := photocolumns[k]; ok {
        param, err := convert(v[0])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        params = append(params, param)
        where += k + " = ? AND " 
    }
}
if len(where) > 0 {
    // prefix the string with WHERE and remove the last " AND "
    where = " WHERE " + where[:len(where)-len(" AND ")]
}

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id, albumId, Title,thumbnailUrl,url from photo" + where, params...)
// ...
```